# Stacked column chart is possible using pykcharts library?

Tags: pykcharts

[image]

**whether this chart is available in PYK if yes which one I  use with PykInteractive Functionality.**

Answer (score 1):

Kiran, 
unfortunately this chart is not available in [PykCharts](http://www.pykcharts.com). Though you may use the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 and connect it with [PykQuery](http://www.pykquery.com/) to get PykInteractive features.